# Python - How to give a Description to a number

Tags: python

Could you guys help me in determining how to do this:

Write a function that determines some characteristics of a certain integer n whose value is taken
from a user input. These characteristics include:
• If n is odd or even
• If n is positive, negative, or neither
• If n is divisible by 3
• If the absolute value of n is between 50 and 99 inclusive
After determining its characteristics, your output should be like this:

Enter a number: 69

=== A SHORT DESCRIPTION OF 69 ===

69 is odd

69 is positive

69 is divisible by 3

The absolute value of 69 is between 50 and 99 inclusive.

---

Here is my code:

```
n = int(input("ENTER A NUMBER: "))
remainder = n % 2
print("===","SHORT DESCRIPTION OF", n,"===")

if (remainder == 0):
    print(n, "is an EVEN NUMBER")
elif (n % 2) == 0:
    print(n, "is an EVEN NUMBER")
else:
    print(n, "is an ODD NUMBER")

if n > 0:
    print(n, "is a POSITIVE NUMBER")
elif n < 0:
    print(n, "is a NEGATIVE NUMBER")
else:
    print(n, "is NEITHER a POSTIVE or a NEGATIVE NUMBER")

if (n % 3) == 0:
    print(n, "is DIVISIBLE by 3")
else:
    print(n, "is not DIVISIBLE by 3")

if 99 >= n >= 50:
    print("The ABSOLUTE VALUE of",n,"is between 50 and 99 INCLUSIVE")
elif n < 0:
    99 >= n >= 50
    print("The ABSOLUTE VALUE of",n,"is between 50 and 99 INCLUSIVE")
elif 99 <= n >= 50:
    print("The ABSOLUTE VALUE of",n,"is not between 50 and 99 INCLUSIVE")
```

It is almost correct but the issue I am facing is the last part of the code on how do I have the "the absolute value of 'n' is/not between 50 and 99 inclusive".

Comment: Why are you duplicating the even test?  You first calculate the remainder (when dividing by 2), then you test it, then you recalculate the remainder and test it again.  That's sloppy logic and bad code.  HInt:  If you know it's odd, it's not going to spontaneously become even when you test it again.

Comment: You could use a `not` operator to negate an existing logic.

Comment: FYI, you did not write a function like the exercise asked you to.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to test if n < 0 then, you can test if either n, or -n is between 50 and 99, in all other cases the absolute value is not between these two.

here is a possible solution:

```
if 99 >= n >= 50 or 99 >= -n >= 50:
    print("The ABSOLUTE VALUE of",n,"is between 50 and 99 INCLUSIVE")
else:
    print("The ABSOLUTE VALUE of",n,"is not between 50 and 99 INCLUSIVE")
```

You also retest the opposite condition when that is actually not necessary. If the first condition is false, it means it's not between 50 and 99, no need to test again.

As a bonus advice, here are some slight improvements to the rest of your code:

```
n = int(input("ENTER A NUMBER: "))
print("===","SHORT DESCRIPTION OF", n,"===")

#You were testing this condition twice!
if (n % 2) == 0:
    print(n, "is an EVEN NUMBER")
else:
    print(n, "is an ODD NUMBER")

if n > 0:
    print(n, "is a POSITIVE NUMBER")
elif n < 0:
    print(n, "is a NEGATIVE NUMBER")
else:
    print(n, "is NEITHER a POSTIVE or a NEGATIVE NUMBER")

if (n % 3) == 0:
    print(n, "is DIVISIBLE by 3")
else:
    print(n, "is not DIVISIBLE by 3")

# you can test both condition at once so you don't have to copypaste the print statement
if 99 >= n >= 50 or 99 >= -n >= 50:
    print("The ABSOLUTE VALUE of",n,"is between 50 and 99 INCLUSIVE")
else:
    print("The ABSOLUTE VALUE of",n,"is not between 50 and 99 INCLUSIVE")
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the answer by @Ran A you can use `abs()`; and once again, there's no need for two tests - just get the absolute value and check it.

But the real issue is that line `elif 99 <= n >= 50:`: you are checking if `n` is greater than 99 and is also greater than 50. This is not what you want. To be honest once you work with the absolute value this test becomes redundant, but let's keep it. So the last part of your code could be something like:

```
n_abs = abs(n)
if 99 >= n_abs >= 50:
    print("The ABSOLUTE VALUE of",n,"is between 50 and 99 INCLUSIVE")
elif 99 > n_abs or n_abs < 50: #this could simply be else:
    print("The ABSOLUTE VALUE of",n,"is not between 50 and 99 INCLUSIVE")
```

Comment: This is not good because n is changed. He is then printing n, and it's gonna be messed up.

Comment: Let's say he enters -20 as a number. The output will be === SHORT DESCRIPTION OF -20 ===
-20 is an EVEN NUMBER
-20 is a NEGATIVE NUMBER
-20 is not DIVISIBLE by 3
The ABSOLUTE VALUE of 20 is not between 50 and 99 INCLUSIVE

Comment: The last line is "The absolute value of 20...." when it should be "The absolute value of -20..."

Comment: @jeekiii I can hardly see that as an issue - but ok, let's use a second variable (in reality one would simply call `abs(n)` in the `if` statement, and use `else` instead of `elif`, but I let the `elif` for demontration purposes)

Comment: I don't agree with your assessment. He gets the wrong output, that is an issue. I do agree that you should but abs(n) in the conditions. Why do you not do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the function you want:

```py
def num_info(n: int) -> None:
    print(f"=== SHORT DESCRIPTION OF {n} ===")

    # even or odd
    if n % 2:
        print(f"{n} is an ODD NUMBER")
    else:
        print(f"{n} is an EVEN NUMBER")

    # positive or negative
    if n > 0:
        print(f"{n} is a POSITIVE NUMBER")
    elif n < 0:
        print(f"{n} is a NEGATIVE NUMBER")
    else:
        print(f"{n} is NEITHER a POSITIVE nor a NEGATIVE NUMBER")

    # divisible by 3
    if n % 3:
        print(f"{n} is not DIVISIBLE by 3")
    else:
        print(f"{n} is DIVISIBLE by 3")

    # absolute value of n is between 50 and 99 (inclusive)
    if 50 <= abs(n) <= 99:
        print(f"The ABSOLUTE VALUE of {n} is between 50 and 99 INCLUSIVE")
    else:
        print(f"The ABSOLUTE VALUE of {n} is not between 50 and 99 INCLUSIVE")
```

You can test it like this:

```py
def main() -> None:
    n = int(input("ENTER A NUMBER: "))
    num_info(n)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It's worth noting that you could break the four parts of your function into their own separate functions to improve readability, but in such a simple example it's not really necessary.

Answer (score -2):

you can use the 'abs' function:

```
  if 99 >= abs(n) >= 50:
        print("The ABSOLUTE VALUE of",n,"is between 50 and 99 INCLUSIVE")
    elif n < 0:
        99 >= abs(n) >= 50
        print("The ABSOLUTE VALUE of",n,"is between 50 and 99 INCLUSIVE")
    elif 99 <= abs(n) >= 50:
        print("The ABSOLUTE VALUE of",n,"is not between 50 and 99 INCLUSIVE")
```

Comment: Yur code won't work for values between 49 and -49